# In MS-Excel - Is there a way to create an Index-match using the current sheet's name as a dynamic reference?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a workbook with many sheets all named as a number (EX: 1, 2, 3... 30). There is additionally a "cover sheet" which holds information on all 30 sheets. Within the cover sheet there are rows of information, including a reference to the sheet name (EX: a row for sheet "7" that has name, status, etc.)

Within each numbered sheet I would like to create an index(match()) reference back to the "cover sheet"... If I am doing this for sheet "7" I can do this successfully with the following function:

column R contains the data I want to display in a cell in sheet "7" 
column X contains the references such as "1", "2", "3", "7", etc.
Notice below how I have to use the absolute reference "7" in the MATCH

```
=INDEX(cover sheet!R5:R200,MATCH(7,RCM!X5:X200,0))
```

Instead of having the absolute reference "7" in the MATCH I would like it to dynamically reference each sheet the cell sits in. I know I can get the name of the sheet with the following formula...

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

When I try to utilize the above function instead of the absolute reference of "7" I get #N/A

In order to try and fix this issue I have tried to convert the reference to a number as the items in Column X on the coversheet are numbers...

When I do type() on the following I get a type 2 or a "Text"

```
=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)
```

I believe in order to make the reference work I need the sheet name to show up as a number. I tried to convert the cell into a number utilizing home-->format cells--> number... this did not work.

I am able to fix the reference if I copy and paste the finished formula as text it still does not work. I tried to write this in VBA to fill the

After copy and paste as text the only way I can fix the reference is if I press the green tab on the cell and actually hit "Convert to Number" it will fix the reference...

```
Sub sheet_name_test()
    Dim sheet_name As String
    Dim file_name As String
    file_name = ChrW(34) & "filename" & ChrW(34) 'ASCII 34 is quotation
    sheet_name = "=MID(CELL(" & file_name & ",A1),FIND(" & ChrW(34) & "]" & ChrW(34) & ",CELL(" & file_name & ",A1))+1,255)"
    'MsgBox sheet_name & vbNewLine & Range("B11").Value
    'Cells(13, 2).Value = sheet_name

    Cells(2, 3) = sheet_name
    Cells(2, 3).Copy
    Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells(2, 3).NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub


'when i tried to record the drop down that says "convert to number" it 
'did not record anything...
'Recorded Macro
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
End Sub
```

I expect that I should be able to use the sheet name in the Index(Match()), but just need to format it in the proper way. My trouble shooting has not worked thus far. Thank you for any help or tips!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to coerce your sheet name to a number you can do something like this:

```
MATCH(1*MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),
      Sheet2!A1:A13,0)
```

or

```
MATCH(VALUE(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255)),
      Sheet2!A1:A13,0)
```

Alternatively, format the sheet names on your cover page as Text

Comment: Thank you Tim!! the =VALUE function solved this. Really appreciate your help.